# Windows Script Host Object Model's Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll referencing same directory as executable

Tags: vb.net, dll, reference, host-object

I have an application that creates desktop shortcuts.  To do this I have to reference the Windows Script Host Object Model.  When I add it as a reference, it always creates the DLL, Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll, in the obj\x86\Debug directory, then references itself to it, rather than looking at wshom.ocx.  Even if I add reference wshom.ocx it reverts to saving the file in the obj\x86\Debug directory.  The problem is if I move my application to another computer without that DLL being present, the program fails to run.

What's the proper way of handling this situation?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would be to ditch the Windows Scripting Host completely.  Here's a link to a method for creating shortcuts without relying on the WSH.  It still uses COM though.

http://vbaccelerator.com/home/NET/Code/Libraries/Shell_Projects/Creating_and_Modifying_Shortcuts/article.asp

Here is a class that someone created that you can use:

http://www.msjogren.net/dotnet/eng/samples/dotnet_shelllink.asp